# How do I make these functions run only when previous has completed in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a hover event, and on hover, I need to set the size of the subnav,add a class to it depending on how wide it is, then show the subnav.  The trouble is, as it is now, it shows the subnav having the original size on first hover, then when I hover a second time it has resized the subnav.

So how do I chain 3 things to run only after the previous has completed:

1. setSubNavWidth2()
2. setSubMenuPos()
3. $(this).children('.sub-menu-div').css('visibility', 'visible');

   ```
    $('.dir').hover(        
           function(){
             if($(this).children('.sub-menu-div').length>0){
                var subnav=$(this).children('.sub-menu-div');
                setSubMenuPos(subnav);
                setSubNavWidth2(subnav);
                  $(this).children('.sub-menu-div').css('visibility', 'visible');
             }              
               $(this).children('.top-level-link').addClass('hoverstyle');              
           },
         function(){
                $(this).children('.sub-menu-div').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $(this).css('background-color','transparent')
                $(this).children('.top-level-link').removeClass('hoverstyle');

           }
       );      

   function setSubNavWidth2(element){
        var sub_nav_width = various calculations that set sub nav width
          $(element).width(sub_nav_width );
   }

    function setSubMenuPos(element){
          //set posiiton of menu
               var position = $(element).parent().position();
               var xPos = position.left;
               var width = $(element).width();
               var parentWidth = $(element).parent().width();
               var newXpos = xPos + parentWidth;
               if(xPos + width > 950 ){                
                     $(element).removeClass('left');
                      $(element).addClass('right');
               }


       }
   ```

Comment: I feel like it would help if you showed us what was in the two function calls on the hoverover definition. Also, if you could make a jsFiddle that replicates your issue then I am sure you would get a much higher quality answer.

Comment: ok, both functions are rather complicated though.  I just need to know really how to queue my functions so one runs after the other.

Comment: Do you think that could possibly be an artifact of applying the class `hoverstyle` after you calculate sizes the first time? Perhaps try adding the class before you call your functions.

Comment: the class is applied to the parent though and all it does is make the background white and text orange

Comment: Your edit shows that you want to do this order: 1, 2, 3. But your code does 2, 1, 3. Are the function calls out of order?

Comment: sorry, the first two are in any order, but I want the last thing to be the element being shown.

Comment: I think the problem I was having is that the elements don't have any width until they are shown.  That is why the correct width is only calculated once they have first been shown, because then they have been displayed in order to get the width the next time the hover function runs..

Comment: should I close this question then?

Comment: Might as well, probably not going to help people in the future because it is so customized.